# How to use IsNumeric on Index Match?

Tags: arrays, vba, indexing, match, isnumeric

I'm strugling to get my code to work. When trying to evaluate if the value found by my `Index(Match())` is a number with `IsNumeric` I get a "Mismatch Error 13" once every other time. When I don't get the error the code seems to work fine.
I would like to know how I can use the value found by the `Index(Match())` in the `IsNumeric` function possibly by storing it in a variable or in any other way.

```
Dim i     As integer
Dim pay   As Variant

For i = 0 To rowz - 1

    pay = Application.Index(target.Sheets("Countries").Range("G3:G" & lastRow), Application.Match(target.Sheets("TEST").Range("D" & 7 + i), target.Sheets("Countries").Range("D3:D" & lastRow), 0))

    If IsNumeric(pay) And pay = "00" Then 'Error appears here
        target.Sheets("TEST").Range("F" & 7 + i).Value = 1
        ElseIf IsNumeric(pay) Then
            target.Sheets("TEST").Range("F" & 7 + i).Value = pay
        ElseIf Left(pay, Len(pay) - 1) = "00" Then
            target.Sheets("TEST").Range("F" & 7 + i).Value = 1
        Else: target.Sheets("TEST").Range("F" & 7 + i).Value = Left(pay, Len(pay) - 1)
    End If

    Next i
```

Comment: It seems so. With your code the marco is consistantly skipping the numerical values formatted as text. Mine would give back the error code once every other time. So once working perfectly fine, and finding the value I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have an error value coming back. Try testing for that first with the following. Also, wouldn't `pay` be `0` if not a string i.e. rather than `"00"`? It can't be both though implicit conversion may hide this.

```
If Not IsError(pay) Then
      If IsNumeric(pay) And pay = 0 Then 
          'Other code

End If
```

Comment: I agree for the `pay = 0` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Including with the IsError? And with the IsError check do you still get the same error? If so, what is the value of pay when the error occurs?

Comment: So the error doesn't appear anymore but the `Inde(Match())` seems to only work for values that look like this IE00014 opposed to numerical values formatted as text

Comment: You are going to need to step through with F8 and check how the program flow differs from what you expect using  test case that fails. I have answered your original query. Please ask a new question with respect to the new problem.